# How to broadcast objects to Slot in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm working on a word segmentation project in Flink, how can I send a jieba object created in the main method to each slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `jieba` object is serializable, then you can pass it to the constructor of some custom function and save it in a non-transient field. When the function is serialized & distributed by Flink to each Task Manager, the object will be deserialized when the function is instantiated.